# Python Curses Rectangle Border

Tags: python, curses

I am making a python program that makes heavy use of the curses.textpad.rectangle function. It draws a rectangle using `─┐│` characters. I would like to know if I could use any other characters as a border. I don't think the function itself supports it, so are there any other functions I could use?

For example, this code uses single lines for the border:

```
from curses.textpad import rectangle
from curses import wrapper

@wrapper
def main(stdscr):
    rectangle(stdscr, 2, 2, 10, 10)
```

I want to use double lines (using `=#║` symbols). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rectangle code shouldn't be too difficult to rewrite to do what you want:

```
def rectangle(win, uly, ulx, lry, lrx):
    """Draw a rectangle with corners at the provided upper-left
    and lower-right coordinates.
    """
    win.vline(uly+1, ulx, curses.ACS_VLINE, lry - uly - 1)
    win.hline(uly, ulx+1, curses.ACS_HLINE, lrx - ulx - 1)
    win.hline(lry, ulx+1, curses.ACS_HLINE, lrx - ulx - 1)
    win.vline(uly+1, lrx, curses.ACS_VLINE, lry - uly - 1)
    win.addch(uly, ulx, curses.ACS_ULCORNER)
    win.addch(uly, lrx, curses.ACS_URCORNER)
    win.addch(lry, lrx, curses.ACS_LRCORNER)
    win.addch(lry, ulx, curses.ACS_LLCORNER)
```

change (monkey patch) the curses.ACS_* or rewrite this function to, say, double_line_rectangle(...) and put the character you want in the curses.X spot.  like this:

```
def rectangle(win, uly, ulx, lry, lrx):
    """Draw a double-line rectangle with corners at the provided upper-left
    and lower-right coordinates.
    """
    win.vline(uly+1, ulx, u'\u2551', lry - uly - 1)
    win.hline(uly, ulx+1, u'\u2551', lrx - ulx - 1)
    win.hline(lry, ulx+1, u'\u2551', lrx - ulx - 1)
    win.vline(uly+1, lrx, u'\u2551', lry - uly - 1)
    win.addch(uly, ulx, u'\u2554')
    win.addch(uly, lrx, u'\u2557')
    win.addch(lry, lrx, u'\u255D')
    win.addch(lry, ulx, u'\u255A')
```

[Here's a lookup for all the cool unicode characters for drawing boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)

Comment: I have tried a few of the characters from the wiki page but none of them render properly in my terminal. I am using neovim and they render just fine, but when I use the terminal emulator in neovim i get strange accented letters except for the double line corners which render fine. I opened a seperate terminal window and I get the same error. I am using windows terminal and tried switching my font from `FiraMono Nerd Font Mono` to `Cascadia Code` but I get the same strange characters. Any advice?

Comment: As a follow-up, I did also use the `u'\u'` strings but they also render like this.

Comment: your first mistake is using `neovim`.  That program tremendously sucks, and I'm uncertain why anyone would use it over proper vim.   On a more serious note, it may also be the case that unicode is not being rendered properly by your terminal emulator.  Have you tried to run the program using powershell?  Also, curses may not include the double-line boxes for compatibility issues just like this.

Comment: I don't think it can be my terminal emulator because I run (neo)via in the same emulator and it looks just fine when I'm editing the file

Comment: As for neovim: I already knew lua and didn't see the point in learning vimscript when neovim is a seemingly perfectly fine alternative....

Comment: Also,  I tried rendering the single line borders and they don't work properly either, which is odd because they work in the textpad.rectangle function just fine. I might look at the source for the rectangle function to see how it is implemented there

Comment: Well, other than reiterating that `neovim` is neither fine nor perfect, I've got nothing more to add.  It's also possible that you need to use ncursesw for the wide characters, but that seems unlikely if you're able to render the normal box characters.  I'm giving your question an upvote and will cross my fingers that a solution presents it self to us.